# Blocks and self from called method

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

Ok, so I understand how to avoid `self` retain cycles with blocks, how about cases when I send a message to self from a method within a block nested deeper in call stack like this:

```
- (void)methodA {
    __block MyClass *blockSelf = self;
    [someObject block:^{
        [blockSelf methodB];
    }];
}

- (void)methodB {
    ...
    [self methodC];
    ...
}

- (void)methodC {
}
```

In this case `[blockSelf methodB]` is fine, but is sending `[self methodC]` from `methodB` causing retain cycle or not? Can't find the answer anywhere...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s no retain cycle there. When a Block literal is defined inside a method, the context that can be captured by the Block is limited to what is *visible inside that method.* In your example:

```
- (void)methodA {
    __block MyClass *blockSelf = self;
    [someObject block:^{
        [blockSelf methodB];
    }];
}
```

the Block literal, namely:

```
^{
    [blockSelf methodB];
}
```

is able to see the following:

1. `self` and `_cmd`, which are hidden parameters available in every Objective-C method. If `-methodA` had formal parameters, the Block literal would be able to see them, too;
2. Any block-scope variables inside the function/method block, i.e., every local variable inside the method and which is visible at the point where the Block literal is defined. In the example, the only local variable inside `-methodA` is `blockSelf` which, because it’s `__block`-qualified, is not retained;
3. Any file-scope variables (aka global variables).

A Block literal is unaware (and, in the general case, cannot be aware) of what happens inside other functions/methods, hence whatever context is available inside called functions/methods is not captured by the Block literal. You only need to worry about the method where the Block literal is defined.

<sup>I’m using Apple’s convention of capitalising Block when referring to closures/lambdas (i.e., `^{}`) and lowercase block when referring to C blocks (i.e., `{}`).</sup>

Comment: Cool, thanks! This would remove a bunch of ugly "parameter hacks" from my helper methods...

Comment: "There’s no retain cycle there." well, it depends on what `someObject` is and whether it retains the block passed to it. If `self` retains `someObject` (say, it's an instance variable), and if `someObject` stores and retains the block passed to `block:`, then there would be a retain cycle.